# How do I make this counter include the string that I need in Android?

Tags: java, android

This code is suppose to display "Hello World" + a counter after each time you press the button. For example: "Hello World!" to "Hello World 1". It currently displays "Hello World!" to "1".

Code:

```
package com.example.victornguyen.updatedengrassignment;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView  showValue;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

    }

    public void button(View view) {
        counter++;
        showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line to:

```
showValue.setText("Hello World "+Integer.toString(counter));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    int counter = 0;
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter ++;
        showValue.setText(" Hello World "+counter);
    }
});
```

hope this will help